# JSON difference between { myParameter : 77 } and { 'myParameter' : 77 }

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I have several AJAX calls to web services in an ASP.Net application, basically I am using JQuery to make the calls but I would like to know the difference (if any) between writing:

```
data: "{ 'myParameter' : 77 }"
```

and

```
data: "{ myParameter : 77 }"
```

I have tried both approaches and they work so what's the difference?

### Edit 1

Ok so according to my understanding, they are valid because they are valid in JavaScript *but they are not strictly JSON valid objects*, so what's the best practice or the recommended use?

Comment: Try to use this one : https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js to convert the data before sending it to Service call..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neither of them are actually valid JSON (which [requires that all key names are *double-quoted* with `"`](http://www.json.org/)). If you’re parsing them later on with `eval` in JavaScript (which used to be the norm), there’s no visible difference, because all three (single quotes, double quotes, and no quotes) are valid in JavaScript object literals – but `eval` is a really bad way to parse JSON, especially now that `JSON.parse` exists.

You should use `JSON.stringify` and produce valid JSON.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ myParameter: 77 }),
```